# Alien Invasion Short Story with American Indians

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alien-invasion

I'm looking to find a story I read years ago in a paperback of alien invasion shorts.

The story takes place in what seems like North America hundreds if not thousands of years before the Europeans arrived. A tribe of Indians stumble across a growing number of geometric shaped aliens that are - if I remember correctly - multi colored and gelatinous... in my mind they are like violent giant intelligent Jello molds - large triangle shaped I believe. 
The aliens start to grow in number and the Indian tribe (or just part of it) attack and fight with the invaders. 
If I remember correctly the Tribe of warriors manage to defeat the aliens in the end - most of the actin takes place in a large grassy area surrounded by forest and maybe mountains.

I remember reading it in the early 1980s.

Comment: Haha, it sounds hilarious!

Comment: The aliens who appeared to have somehow consumed fruit cocktail lasted the longest. :-)

Answer (score 5):

There was a very old story (1931!) by P. Schuyler Miller
called "Tetrahedra of Space"
I read many many years ago, almost the entire plot has long gone from my memory. However the description given of the alien invaders brought the image back.
[image]

Comment: "Tetrahedra of Space" is available at the Internet Archive, both the original [*Wonder Stories*, November 1931](https://archive.org/details/Wonder_Stories_v03n06_1931-11) and the reprint in [*Startling Stories*, September 1948](https://archive.org/stream/Startling_Stories_v18n01_1948-09#page/n83/mode/2up). The OP would probably have read it in Asimov's *Before the Golden Age*. If I remember right, it's set in **South** America, in the **20th century**, and the Indians **don't** fight off the invaders. I'll have to reread it.

Comment: Hmm. The OP says he read it in "a paperback of alien invasion shorts". Asimov's *Before the Golden Age* did have paperback editions, but it did not have an alien-invasion theme. If "Tetrahedra of Space" was in any other anthologies, the ISFDB doesn't know about them.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely [Les Xipéhuz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Xip%C3%A9huz) by J.H. Rosny Ainé (1887/88), which takes place in Mesopotamia 1000 years before the rise of Ninive, Babylon and Ecbatane.
The story does not tell whether the shapes are extraterrestrial or native earthlings, but the grow in number and they can only move within a certain area which expands proportionally to their number. They are in the shape of cone, cylinder and cuboid, and individuals change from one shape to another.
The shapes emerge inside a forest and while their number increases expand their territory into the surrounding plains. Nearby mountains are mentioned.